# Iterate through a specified directory in Android

Tags: android, file, loops

i am trying to develop a security application on Android and i want to iterate through the filenames of a specific directory so that i can compare the hash value of each file in the directory.

I have already found out how to do the hashing but for the iterating part i am confused on how it works.

Answer (score 40, accepted):

You mean you want to traverse a directory recursively?

Something like this:

```
    public void traverse (File dir) {
       if (dir.exists()) {
        File[] files = dir.listFiles();
        if (files != null) {

        for (int i = 0; i < files.length; ++i) {
            File file = files[i];
            if (file.isDirectory()) {
                traverse(file);
            } else {
                // do something here with the file
            }
        }
      }
     }
    }
```

Comment: Is there a performance penalty for declaring a file variable inside the for loop over and over again?  Wouldn't it be better to declare the file variable outside the for loop only one time?

Comment: @joshgoldeneagle, There's no *significant* or completely no performance penalty since all `File` objects are already allocated on the heap, the `file` variable inside the loop is just a reference sitting on the stack, from the byte code generated by code declaring the `file` variable inside or outside the loop, I can only see that the stack slot number for the variable is different. Always declare variables within their possible smallest scope, readability is far more important than that little efficiency improvement.

Comment: How can I access and iterate through the classes in my Android project's directories?

Comment: Remember to check `files!=null` before the `for` loop, otherwise you will get a `NullPointerException`.